# Hibernate Transformers.aliasToBean Josn String to List<>

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a table called user_request and it has request_payload column of type text and I want to map this column to List in my DTO class using result transformer

```
 private Integer id;
 private List<userRequest> userRequestList;
 // setter and getters
}
```

is possible to get result like this from db using result transformer

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. Just look into the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query) which nicely explains how you can do this ;)